# A way to check if it is in the landscape or portrait mode in Xamarin.Android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.android

I'm using  C# in Visual Studio 2017 and Xamarin.Android (not Xamarin.Forms) in my project. To be clear, I'm using "Cross Platform App(Xamarin)" and not using "Class Library (Xamarin.Forms). I want it to work on both IOs and Android.

My problem is I want to program my app to look like   ^ ^ in landscape mode and <
^  in portrait mode(please look at it like it is in portrait mode). Basically I want to rotate the first one and put it on top, and doesn't wanna change the second one and put it on the bottom.

I searched for a way that how to check if it is in the landscape or portrait mode. Everything that I found in the forums suggest me to use a function that is in Xamarin.Forms, even Xamarin University itself. But I cannot create a new project and carry each class into it. Is there any way that you know how to check if it is in the landscape or portrait mode in Xamarin.Droid?

Answer (score 0):

To control the orientation on Android, open MainActivity.cs and set the orientation using the attribute decorating.

```
 namespace MyRotatingApp.Droid
{
    [Activity (Label = "MyRotatingApp.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation,
    ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Landscape)] **//This is what controls orientation**
    public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
}
```

Comment: At the point "global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity" it gives an error at Forms and says "The type or namespace name "Forms does not exist in the namespace "Xamarin"".  I said that I'm using Xamarin.Android (not Xamarin.Forms) in my project. Maybe that can be the problem? It also gives errors at ConfigChanges

Comment: Check this link https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/handling_rotation/