# How can I access screen width and height of Android mobile in the shared code?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

How can I access screen width and height of Xamarin.Android device in the shared code? I could not use Resources. It could not find Resources in the given context.

To be clear, I want to show different uı design for different orientations(portrait and landscape). Hence I want to reach the tablets/mobilephones orientation in the shared code.

Here is my first question that asks is there a way for to check if it is landscape or portrait:
[A way to check if it is in the landscape or portrait mode in Xamarin.Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45295538/a-way-to-check-if-it-is-in-the-landscape-or-portrait-mode-in-xamarin-android/45298001#45298001)

I think screen width and height of Android mobile in the shared code would help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is actually an excellent little guide on detecting screen size in xamarin.android that can be found on the [xamarin developer guide website](https://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/resources/device_specific/detect_screen_size/).

In the 'Activity.cs' in the onCreat method simply add the below:

```
public static Rotation screenOrientation;

protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
    SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

    var metrics = Resources.DisplayMetrics;
    var widthInDp = ConvertPixelsToDp(metrics.WidthPixels);
    var heightInDp = ConvertPixelsToDp(metrics.HeightPixels);

    if(widthInDp > heightInDp)
    {
        screenOrientation = Rotation.Landscape;
    }
    else
    {
        screenOrientation = Rotation.Portrait;
    }
}
```

I'd use a little enum somewhere if you would like to easily differentiate between landscape and portrait.

```
public enum Rotation
{
    Landscape,
    Portrait
}
```

I think something like that would do the trick.

Comment: I am not able to use because I'm not using Xamarin.Forms. I'm using Xamarin.Android.

Comment: @KaanEKİN because you've included the xamarin.forms tag in your OP you've gotten THREE forms based answers, you need to be more careful, I've submitted an edit.

Comment: sorry about that, new here

Comment: @KaanEKİN it's ok buddy, when I get chance I'll edit my answer to relate to android.

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

`onConfigurationChanged` will help you detect if the device is landscape or portrait. Follow [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13411391/android-device-onconfigurationchanged-event-does-not-handling-orientation)

If you really want to get screen width or height. Try this

```
/**
 * @param activity Context
 * @return a integer value represent the width of physical device
 */
public static int getScreenHeight(Activity activity) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    return metrics.heightPixels;
}

/**
 * @param activity Context
 * @return a integer value represent the width of physical device
 */
public static int getScreenWidth(Activity activity) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(metrics);
    return metrics.widthPixels;
}
```

Comment: I put these codes into MainActivity.cs. Now how can I call them?

Answer (score 0):

The below code will help to design mobile screens on the basis of mobile screen height and width.

Design based on this it will fit all mobile resolutions.

**PCL:**

**App.cs**

```
public class App : Application
{                     
  public static int screenHeight, screenWidth;

 public App()
  {           
    MainPage = new UserLogin();
    //The root page of your application         
   }

   protected override void OnStart()
   {
     // Handle when your app starts
   }

protected override void OnSleep()
{
    // Handle when your app sleeps
}

protected override void OnResume()
{
    // Handle when your app resumes
   }
 }
```

**Xamarin.Android:**

**MainActivity.cs**

#region For screen Height & Width

```
    var pixels = Resources.DisplayMetrics.WidthPixels;
    var scale = Resources.DisplayMetrics.Density;

    var dps = (double)((pixels - 0.5f) / scale);

    var ScreenWidth = (int)dps;

    App.screenWidth = ScreenWidth;

    //RequestedOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait;

    pixels = Resources.DisplayMetrics.HeightPixels;
    dps = (double)((pixels - 0.5f) / scale);

    var ScreenHeight = (int)dps;
    App.screenHeight = ScreenHeight;
```

## endregion

**Xamarin.iOS**

**AppDelegate.cs**

```
#region For Screen Height & Width

  App.screenWidth = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Width;
      App.screenHeight = (int)UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds.Height;
```

#endregion

**PCL:**

If you used MVVM pattern you have to get these ScreeenHeight and ScreenWidth in ViewModel Then give height and widths for your Views and Layouts.

```
         // The below two lines will use to get the MOBILE SCREEN HEIGHT && WIDTH in ViewModel
          int heightScreen=App.screenHeight;
          int widthScreen=App.screenHeigh;
```

**XAML Design:**

**UserLogin.xaml**

```
   <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:local="clr-
  SreenSizeDemo;assembly=SreenSizeDemo" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" 
   x:Class="SreenSizeDemo.UserLogin">
  <StackLayout>
   <Label x:Name="lblTitle" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
   <Image x:Name="imgProfile"  Source="Logo.png" />
  <StackLayout>
  <ContentPage>
```

**UserLogin.xaml.cs**

```
  public partial class UserLogin : BaseContentPage
  {
          // Here you get the MOBILE SCREEN HEIGHT && WIDTH
          int heightScreen=App.screenHeight;
          int widthScreen=App.screenHeight;

 public UserLogin()
     {
                       lblTitle.FontSize=height=Screen/36.8;
                     //The above value is equal to fontsize =20
                     imgProfile.HeightRequest=heightScreeen/10;
                     imgProfile. WidthRequest=heightScreeen/10;
            }
      }
```

**C# Design:**

```
 public class UserLogin: ContentPage
      {
          // Here you get the MOBILE SCREEN HEIGHT && WIDTH
          int heightScreen=App.screenHeight;
          int widthScreen=App.screenHeight;

          public UserLogin()
               {
                   Label lab = new Label()
                    {
                      FontSize = heightScreen/ 36.8
                      //the above value is equal to fontsize =20
                    };

                   Image imgProfile=new Image()
                    {
                         Source="Logo.png",
                         HeightRequest=heightScreeen/10,
                         WidthRequest=heightScreeen/10
                  }
          }
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you are trying to set the height and width of some controls relative to the screen size. If you are using Xamarin Forms, the proportional dimensions could be achieved using Grid. The whole idea about using Xamarin Forms is that you don't have to worry about the form factor.

So in your Xaml you could use `Grid` in the following way

```
 <ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms" xmlns:local="clr-SreenSizeDemo;assembly=SreenSizeDemo" xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml" x:Class="SreenSizeDemo.UserLogin">
  <Grid x:Name="ContentGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!--This row will resize depending upon the size of the content within it-->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto">
        <!--This will take 10% of  your total screen height-->
        <RowDefinition Height="0.1*">
        <!--This will take rest of the available the screen height (i.e. ScreenHeight - Row0Height - Row1Height)-->
        <RowDefinition Height="*">
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Label x:Name="lblTitle" Grid.Row="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"/>
        <!--You don't need to set both height and width of the image, setting either of them is enough. Unless your ImageAscpect property neither of these AspectFill, AspectFit values-->
        <Image x:Name="ImgProfile" Grid.Row="1" Source="Logo.png"/>
        <!--Rest of your contents go in third row-->
    </Grid>
  <ContentPage>
```

The only thing that you may have to do in the code behind is setting up the `FontSize` for the label control.In this case, instead of using the screen size, You can set the font size relative to the height of Grid.

```
public UserLogin()
{
  lblTitle.FontSize = ContentGrid.Height/10;
}
```

Also if getting the screen size is inevitable I would recommend you to use dependency service to obtain the screen size instead using global static properties